# Can I include bash/sh files as dependencies in package.json?

Tags: javascript, bash, npm, sh

I have a bash script which I wrote for publishing modules to npm: `publish.sh`
As I still work on tweaking this script a lot, every time I change it, I need to make the changes in every copy of it in every npm module I am managing.

Is there a way to include this as a dependency in my package.json file so that I just need to run `npm update; npm install` in order to update it? Maybe the sh file would need to be executed by some wrapper javascript or something like that..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question a few years later:
What I was looking for was to be able to add the following to my package.json file:

```
  "name": "your-package-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "bin": "./path/to/your-script.sh"
```

or

```
  "bin": {
    "command-name-1": "./path/to/your-first-script.sh",
    "command-name-2": "./path/to/your-second-script.sh"
  }
```

So that they would be installed to the .bin file under `node_modules`.

I haven't tried this by referencing a URI to a version controlled .sh file, but that would be the ideal flow I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

"scripts": {
"start": "sh ./scripts/publish.sh",
...
}

Comment: That's running the script using npm run start, I meant adding it as a dependency (maybe needing to be wrapped in a javascript module if that is possible)

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to the script in a single project, you can put it in the `"scripts"` object in `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
  "publish": "/bin/sh publish.sh"
}
```

The above can be run with `npm run publish`. See [`npm run-script` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/run-script.html) for more information.

If you literally want to add the shell script as a dependency that can be installed (from the public registry or a private registry) with `npm install`, you can absolutely do that. Lots of not-JavaScript executable things are available in the `npm` repository. You'll want to create a `package.json` for the dependency and specify the location of your shell script with [the `"bin"` entry](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin).

An example package you can look at if you get stuck is [notes.sh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/notes.sh). The [source code is on GitHub](https://github.com/xwmx/nb). Look at the `package.json` to see how they specified the scripts to run in the `"bin"` entry. You'll still need to create a `"script"` entry in your other project to run the installed shell script (or you can run it as an npm hook) though, unless you're running it manually or spawning a child process in your code or something.

Comment: That's running the script using `npm run start`, I meant adding it as a dependency (maybe needing to be wrapped in a javascript module if that is possible)

Comment: I had originally included that information but then deleted it figuring it was not what you were looking for. I'll add it back again now.

Comment: OK, I put enough information to hopefully point you in the right direction, but if I'm still misunderstanding or there's otherwise a gap, let me know.

Comment: Thinking about it more: What problem are you trying to solve here? I'm not sure what installing it as a dependency gets you. Unless the idea is to reuse the same shell script in many packages?

Comment: Pretty much yes, I'll check this one out thanks for the suggestion!